# Unable to reach Breakpoint in javafx.scene.control.MenuItem (JavaFX, Netbeans 8)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, javafx, menuitem

I'm trying to add a MenuBar to my JavaFX Project. Everything went well, until
I added a second MenuItem to a Menu.

```
...
    final Menu options = new Menu("Options");  // create the Menu

    final MenuItem settings1 = new MenuItem("Settings");  // create the first MenuItem
    settings1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage sSettings = new Stage();
            GridPane vGp = new GridPane();

            Button ok = new Button("Ok");
            ok.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    ...
                    // CODE I NEED TO DEBUG
                    ...
                    sSettings.close();
                }

            });

            sSettings.setTitle("Settings");
            sSettings.setScene(new Scene(vGp, 800, 300));
            sSettings.show();
        }
    });
    options.getItems().add(settings1);

    final MenuItem settings2 = new MenuItem("Settings");  // create the second MenuItem
...
```

Now, if I add a second MenuItem the same way i created the MenuItem `settings1`, 
everything would work fine. The whole Code would be executed like I want it.

My Problem is the debugging of this Code. It is not possible to debug the Code, which will be executed, when clicked on the OK-Button of the opened Stage created by the second MenuItem.
The Code will be executed, but the Debugger won't stop inside the definition.

My only option is to comment every single MenuItem defined before the MenuItem I want to work on. And I think it's going to be annoying very fast.

Anyone else got the same Problem? Maybe its IDE specific:

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1 with jdk1.8.0_11 on Linux.
Code Example: https://gist.github.com/mul8or/8b94e440eda49b2d8fed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to debug the code inside the OK-Button perfectly fine in Netbeans same environment as you in Windows.
I set the breakpoint at

```
sSettings.close();
```

and the debugger stop at the breakpoint perfectly fine. It might be due to some condition specified in other parts of your code or you attach the wrong button?

I've also managed to debug this code perfectly fine in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it again with minimal code, it still doesn't work. This is the Code: https://gist.github.com/mul8or/8b94e440eda49b2d8fed .

Comment: You, it is working. Since there are two identical function in both settings, perhaps you set the breakpoint in the wrong function?